# C++ C2681 overloaded function, dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line-interface, managed-c++, dynamic-cast

I'm learing Visual C++ from Julian Templeman's book "Microsoft Visual C++ .NET", 2005 edition. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

I know that it deals with old Managed C++ which is replaced by C++/CLI, so I must change some text in code to work in cli.

However, when there is code about to print again window content when window get minimized or back, i get error

C2681: 'overloaded function' : invalid expression type for dynamic_cast

Here is the function where it throws that:

```
void Form_Paint(Object^ pSender, PaintEventArgs^ pe)
{
    Graphics^ gr = pe->Graphics;
    Pen^ pen1 = gcnew Pen(Color::Black);

    for(int i=0; i<list->Count; i++)
    {
        Line^ pline = dynamic_cast<Line^>(pline->GetType);   //C2681
        gr->DrawLine(pen1, pline->p1.X,pline->p1.Y,pline->p2.X,pline->p2.Y);
    }
}
```

The original from book looks like that:

```
void Form_Paint(Object* pSender, PaintEventArgs* pe)
{
    Graphics* gr = pe->Graphics;
    Pen* pen1 = new Pen(Color::Black);

    for(int i=0; i<list->Count; i++)
    {
        Line* pline = dynamic_cast<Line*>(pline->get_Item(i));
        gr->DrawLine(pen1, pline->p1.X,pline->p1.Y,pline->p2.X,pline->p2.Y);
    }
}
```

Also I don't know how to write `pline->get_Item(i)` in CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `pline->GetType` should be `pline->GetType()` because `GetType()` is a function.

Comment: If I put () in to end it compiles, but doesn't redraw form's content, if I put to end (i), it throws error C2660: 'System::Object::GetType' function does not take 1 arguments